# How to speed up the count down?

Tags: javascript, html, countdowntimer

I am working on a basic countdown using Javascript where, the countdown starts from 0 and then ends till 24 as thats the idea of the countdown, I want to end it at 24. Here's the code:

```
var count=0;

var counter=setInterval(timer, 50); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  count=count+1;
  if (count >= 24)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     //counter ended, do something here
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=24 ;

     return;
  }

  //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
     document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=count ; // watch for      spelling

}
```

Now the thing is that if you notice this, the countdown happens very fast, this is the intended effect. However the question is this, **Is there a way to have a smooth easing type effect, where the countdown starts slowly and then speeds up by the end ?** How to achieve that effect ?

Thanks for your response.

**EDIT:** Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/4nnms1gz/), to see the countdown in action and to gain a deeper insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timeout which runs only once then add extra time and run the timeout again until you reach 24.

```
var count=0;
var ms = 200;
var step = 5;
var counter=setTimeout(timer, ms); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  count=count+1;
  if (count <= 24)
  {
    //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
     document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=count ; // watch for spelling
     ms = ms - step;
     counter = setTimeout(timer, ms);

  }

}
```

Comment: The original solution started fast and slowed down, but the reverse was desired. I have updated this solution to match the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is quite flexible and the easing happens quite nicely, as in, i can play around with the values.

Comment: @NathanTaylor Reverse ? how does that work ? It starts fast and ends slowly?

Comment: @ZubairAnwar I changed the solution to start fast and slow down, previously it started slowly and sped up.

Comment: Was it something like this ? HAHA !! It dint occur to me that it could be done in 2 opposite ways, here i worked on the opposite animation, is this right ? I know its contrary to what I want however, this is something cool when you mentioned it. [Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/24ax4ecm/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use setTimeout instead of setInterval and another variable for setTimeout.

```
    var count=0;
    var speed = 1000;
    timer();

    function timer()
    {
      count++;

      //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
         document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML=count ; // watch for      spelling

      if (count >= 24)
      {
         return;
      }

      speed = speed / 6 * 5; // or whatever
      setTimeout(timer, speed);

    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nnms1gz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout will give you more control on your counter.Here is a working example where you can handle the speed of your counter.It will give you a time increase of 30ms to 70ms to each call to `time` function

```js
var count=0;
var loop=1000;
var interval;

var text=document.getElementById('countdown');
var range=document.getElementById('range');
var btn=document.getElementById('btn');
var span=document.getElementById('val');

range.addEventListener('change',function(e){
   span.innerHTML=range.value+' ms';
});
btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   timer(parseInt(range.value));
 
});

function timer(time)
{
  
   console.log(time);
  if (count < 24)
  {
     count=count+1;
     text.value=count;
  
   
     loop-=time;
  
  interval=setTimeout(function(){
                            timer(time);
                         },loop);
  
     if(count>=24){
    clearTimeout(interval);
    return;
  }
  }
  

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='countdown' value='0'></br>
<input type='range' id='range' max='70' min='30' value='30' >increase by:<span id='val'></span></br>

<input type='button' value='start' id='btn' ></br>
```

Comment: Sweet Full control, of the easing effect.