# Loop through 24 hours with adjustable loop time

Tags: javascript, jquery

My objective is to create a timer that loops from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`.

The catch is that the duration of the loop - a variable which we can call `looptime` - should be adjustable.  If `looptime` is changed to 10000, then loop should complete in 10 seconds, if changed to 100000, it should complete in 100 seconds, and so on.

I am new to javascript and have created a normal clock with the code below - but it only loops according to the actual time of day - how would one speed up or slow down this clock using a separate variable?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
</head>
<style>
#counter {
  background: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="counter">
    <p></p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 0 + d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#counter').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);

// -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/q/28000415/215552, but it's hard to tell, since you haven't really attempted anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this just made some changes to @Jonas answer ;)

```js
var seconds=0;
var increasepersecond=10;//a regular timer

//Call according to speed
function countAndDisplay(){
   var time=[];
   [60,60,24].reduce(function(left,max,i){
      time[i]= ('0' + (left%max)).slice(-2);
      return (left-time[i])/max;
   },seconds);
   
   jQuery('#counter').html(time.reverse().join(":"))
  seconds+=increasepersecond;
}

setInterval(countAndDisplay,1000/increasepersecond);// Run timer accoring to incresed speed
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
</head>
<style>
#counter {
  background: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="counter">
    <p></p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

// -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, @govind, though is there a way to display single digits like 1, 2 as `01`,`02`, etc.?

Comment: here's a solution:   `if(days < 10){days = "0" + days;}
  if(hours < 10){hours = "0" + hours;}
  if(minutes < 10){minutes = "0" + minutes;}
  if(seconds < 10){seconds = "0" + seconds;}`

Comment: For taking over 90% from my answer, ypu could at least give an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to count up manually:

```
var seconds=0;
var increasypersecond=1;//a regular timer

//or

increasepersecond=60*60*24/10 ;//or do all in 10 seconds

//or

var looptime=10;//all in 10 seconds
increasepersecond=60*60*24/looptime;

//call this each second (or faster)
function countAndDisplay(){
   var time=[];
   [60,60,24].reduce(function(left,max,i){//sets up the time array
      time[i]=left%max;
      return (left-time[i])/max;
   },seconds);
  console.log(time.reverse().join(":"));
  seconds+=increasepersecond;
}

setInterval(countAndDisplay,1000);//regular
```

Comment: is it possible to do from `00:00:00` without getting current seconds of the day ?

Comment: @the_darkside to easy. SImply seconds=0;

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var time = 10000;

var counter = setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 0 + d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#counter').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, time);


clearInterval(counter);

time = 100000;
counter();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I would do this in two parts.  The first part I will describe will be the function to increment time by one second (for moving forward through time) and adjust the minute and hour as necessary.  I will show pseudo code below:

```
function incrementSeconds(hours,minutes,seconds,secondsIncrement) {
    seconds += secondsIncrement;

    if (seconds > 59) {
        seconds -= 60;
        minutes += 1;
    }

    if (minutes == 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours += 1;
    }

    if (hours == 24) {
        //at this point, the time will be
        // 24:00:00
    }
}
```

The function above basically adds *secondsIncrement* number of seconds to the current time, and if it is > 59, adjusts the minutes and hours accordingly.

Then, if you want to increment the clock based on your variable, you can use the following:

```
var clockInterval = setIntervalfunction() {
    incrementSeconds(hours,minutes,seconds,10);
},looptime/8640);
```

That last bit sets a java time interval.  The function will be called once every x milliseconds (where x is defined in argument 1 of setInverval).  There are 86400 seconds in a day, so the first argument will need to factor that in.  However, I have condensed it to 8640, and have set argument 3 of increment seconds to 10, so it changes the clock by 10 seconds every call.  This is to reduce the number of calls to that function.

The reason we are calling *setInterval* with a variable in front *clockInterval* is to give us a handle to the timer object.  That way, when you want to stop the interval, you can call

```
clearTimeout(clockInterval);
```

Comment: incrementSeconds(hours,minutes,seconds,11); will break your code ( that should be ajustable)

Comment: Can you explain how?  It should be able to take any value of seconds up to 60 (I didn't account for the case where it is greater than that).

Comment: sorry, wrong example. But if incrementSeconds is e.g. 600, it wont work properly

Comment: Yes, to account for that, you can simply add a while loop to continually increment the minute and decrement the seconds by 60 until the seconds < 60 (the same will need to be done for hours)